# Angular 2 Final port :4200 not working with ip (192.168.0.xxx:4200) only localhost:4200

Tags: angular-cli

I'm trying to test my "Angular 2 Final" (1.0.0-beta.15) app on my other mobile devices an PCs, but I cannot get to work the 192.168.0.xxx:4200 address, only the localhost:4200... not even in my development Mac.

When I use localhost:4200 everything works fine, the issue is with the IP version.

I'm updating from the angular beta 2.0.0-beta.6 when the port used to be 3000.

I tried changing the port to 3006 with:
ng serve --port 3006

but the same issue.

Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just specify the IP in **--host** option like **ng serve --host 192.16.1.1**

Now you can visit `http://192.16.1.1:4200` in your browser and it will work

Answer (score 6):

As of version `angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.15`.

First of all, localhost (or `127.0.0.0`) and `192.168.x.y` are different network interfaces.

The *node.js* server started by `ng serve` listens only on `127.0.0.1` (aka localhost) with port `4200`. Thus it doesn't accept requests to your local network IP (`192.168.x.y`). You can check it via `netstat` or similar utility.

If you want the *node.js* to listen on all accessible interfaces (aka IP `0.0.0.0`) you can do this by specifying the listening IP explicitly by `ng serve --host 0.0.0.0`.

---

I've created an issue so you can track it: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/2275

Answer (score 0):

Run command " ng serve --host=0.0.0.0 --disable-host-check "

this will disable the host check and make your port accessible with IP address